# MSAL use WithParentActivityOrWindow with UWP handle will white screen and stuck

Tags: c#, msal

I want use MSAL API to signin my microsoft account.

I call the code in wpf ui thread,and I want the Authorization page show on the other uwp,so i use the code:

```
IntPtr handle = Win32Helper.FindWindowW("uwpClassName", "uwpName");
            authResult = await otApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                                .WithParentActivityOrWindow(handle)     
                            .WithPrompt(Microsoft.Identity.Client.Prompt.SelectAccount)
                                .ExecuteAsync();
```

The Authorization page show on the uwp,but it is white screen and stuck.

When I use the wpf window handle, it is normal, but not for uwp windows handle.